# How to enter the condition to check 0 or more than 0 in case

Tags: shell, case

I am trying to use case to run this function

```
if [[ $input -gt 0 || $input -eq 0 ]];
```

Is it possible to put in case to test the input for greater than 0 or equal to 0, or even 0 and less than 0, in case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If only integers need to be handled and `-0` is not need to be handled correctly,
the following works:

```bash
case "$input" in
''|*[!0-9-]*|[0-9-]*-*)
  echo "invalid input"      
  ;;
[0-9]*)
  echo "input >= 0"
  ;;
-[1-9]*)
 echo "input < 0"
 ;;
*)
 echo "invalid input"
 ;;
esac
```

But it is usually better to use `if .. then .. elif ... then .. else .. fi` constructs for distinction of cases with more complicated expressions than `case` with pattern matching.

Comment: This won't work for something like `123asd`, `-1aa`.

Comment: @cuonglm Is there other ways to catch those, i'm doing a input for stock, if the stock is 0 or less than 0, the command will fail, but if the user keys in other characters like string + integer, how do i catch those

Comment: @jofel: No, your solution can't catch `123ad`.

Comment: @jofel if i were to use if, is it possible to combine -ge and -eq together

Comment: @Zac - combine them...? You mean `[ num -gt -1 ]`?

Comment: @jofel: It still fail for `123-123`.

Comment: @cuonglm thanks. I also included this case.

Answer (score 3):

This sample `sh` script validates that a variable is an integer.

```
#!/bin/sh

num=$1

if [ $num -eq $num ] 2> /dev/null
then
    case 1 in
        $(($num < 0))     ) echo $num is negative.;;
        $(($num <= 100))  ) echo $num is between 0 and 100.;;
        $(($num <= 1000)) ) echo $num is between 100 and 1000.;;
        *                 ) echo $num is greater than 1000.;;
    esac
else
    echo $num is not a number.
fi
```

We verify the variable is a number by using the `-eq` operator. We need to suppress its output to `stderr` in case it's not a number.

If the variable contains an integer, the `case` will then evaluate ranges in the laid out form. The expressions `$(( some comparison ))` will either evaluate to "true" (1) or "false" (0); this way, you can test any given list of ranges.

Comment: I’ll admit that the other answers to this question are poor examples of this, but we like our answers to include an explanation. Why are you using `expr` when you don’t need to?  Why are you using a constant *word* and a variable *pattern* in your `case` statement. This seems unnecessarily complicated and convoluted.

Comment: I've modified the script to make it clear and added an explanation of what it does. Hope it helps.

Comment: Shellcheck: `SC2004 (style): $/${} is unnecessary on arithmetic variables.` May lead to "subtle bugs": https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2004

Answer (score 0):

```
[ "$input" -gt -1 ] || exit
```

...or...

```
case ${input:?NULL} in 
(?*[!0-9]*|[!-0-9]*|[!0-9]) ! : ;;
(-*[!0]*)  echo \<0 ;;
(*[!0]*)   echo \>1 ;;
(0*)       echo 0   ;;
esac
```

Comment: @jofel - to which alternative do you refer? If you mean `(*)` matching zero then have you tested this? The first var expansion exits the shell for a null value. The next in line matches any char which is not 0-9, the next any which is not 0 - 1 or more 0 characters is the only possibility there.

Comment: sorry, I was wrong. Thought your are using bashims.

Comment: @jofel - I don't think so - that should be fully POSIX portable syntax. Besides - I never much liked `bash`.

Answer (score 0):

```
case $([[ $input =~ ^-?[0-9]+$ ]] && [[ $input -gt 0 || $input -eq 0 ]] ; echo $?) in
0)
        echo "good"
        ;;
1)
        echo "bad"
        ;;
*)
        echo "weird"
        ;;
esac
```

If you do not like the complexity inside the case, at least the regex matching works well and simple.